# Java vfs2 FileSystemException invalid privatekey. How to solve it?

Tags: java, vfs, spring-integration-sftp, apache-commons-vfs, apache-vfs

In my springboot application, i am transferring a file to sftp. I want to authenticate it only with username and password. However my java code still looking for private key to send, and i am getting the bellow error. How can i solve the below error. What changes do i need in the java class?

Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not load private key from "/Users/123456/.ssh/id_rsa".

Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@180bc464

here is my code:

```
StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();
            String serverAddress = "test.rebex.net";
            String userId = "demo";
            String password = "password";
            String remoteDirectory = "/IN";
            String filepath = "/Users/1234/Documents/TestNotes.txt";
            File file = new File(filepath);
            manager.init();
            FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();
            SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(opts, "no");
            SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, true);
            SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setTimeout(opts, 10000);
            String sftpUri = "sftp://" + userId + ":" + password +  "@" + serverAddress + "/" + remoteDirectory + filepath;
            FileObject localFile = manager.resolveFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(sftpUri, opts);
            remoteFile.copyFrom(localFile, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);
            System.out.println("File upload successful");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's solved with below one line of code:

```
SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setIdentities(opts, new File[0]);
```